# MacOS issue with loading url in web-view

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, webview

I have done with codes below but I'm having problem loading the `webview` with an url which show an error with on runtime

> Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

so please help me with, i have just started with `macOS` application development,

Thanks,

```
import Cocoa

import WebKit


class ViewController: NSViewController, WebFrameLoadDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!

    let urlpath = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //let url = "https:www.apple.com"
        //self.webView.mainFrame.load(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)! as URL))

        webView.policyDelegate = self as! WebPolicyDelegate

        webView.mainFrame.load(NSURLRequest(url: self.urlpath as URL ) as URLRequest!)

    }


    override var representedObject: Any? {

        didSet {

            // Update the view, if already loaded.

        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't implement the WebPolicyDelegate so

```
webView.policyDelegate = self as! WebPolicyDelegate
```

will fail.

self (ViewController) does not implement WebPolicyDelegate.

You need to do:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, WebFrameLoadDelegate, WebPolicyDelegate {
```

and implement the delegate.

Also make sure that your webView

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!)
```

is connected to your webView in your Interface Builder!